# Angular2 No Provider for service in child component

Tags: angular2-services

I have created a bare bones app to show the error I am getting when trying to inject a service into a child component. I am injecting the services into the providers section of the app.module.ts so I thought that would make the services global in the app. If i remove the service from the constructor argument from the test.compononent.ts everything works. I would really appreciate any help with this one!

Here is the error message I am getting.

```
core.umd.js:3072 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for UserService!
```

Here is the **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { NameService } from './services/name.service';
import { TestComponent } from './component/test.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,TestComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
   providers: [
    UserService,
    NameService
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { NameService } from './services/name.service';
import { TestComponent } from './component/test.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>My First Angular App</h1>
    <test-component></test-component>
  `,

})
export class AppComponent { 

  constructor(private nameService: NameService, private userService:UserService) {}
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: '<h3>test component</h3>'
})
export class TestComponent { 

  constructor(private userService:UserService) {}
}
```

**name.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NameService {
    getName():string {
        return 'name1';
    }
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NameService } from './name.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private nameService: NameService) {}
    getUser():string {
        return 'user1';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code - literally copy/pasted everything - and it ran fine for me.

Comment: well gosh thats frustrating! Would you mind pasting your package.json, perhaps i am using a different version of a lib?

Comment: So I just figured it out, i set a compiler directive to typscript to javascript files in a dist directory.  The fix was changing it back so the js files are in the same place as the ts files and changing the packages to point to that location. Not sure how to make it work with the js files in a seperate location though..